# SQL to union all two results and take values into different columns from different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tax table with Id, Tax, insurance columns as below

[image]

similarly i have Insurance table with same columns

[image]

Now i want the results of my query to pull all the ID's from both tables and just Tax column from tax table and Insurance column from insurance table and make the other values null  as below

[image]

How can i achieve this in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `FULL OUTER JOIN` :

```
select coalesce(t.id, i.id) as id, t.tax, i.insurance 
from tax t full outer join 
     insurance i
     on t.id = i.id
order by 1;
```

Comment: @rslemos. .  Yes specially for `SQL Server`